# Doubly Linked List not printing

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I'm messing around with a double linked list right now and I can't seem to print the data the linked list contains.
Here is my code:

```
public class Box<E> {
private DoubleListNode<E> head;
private DoubleListNode<E> tail;
private int size;

public Box() {
    head = new DoubleListNode<E>();
    tail = new DoubleListNode<E>();
    size = 0;
}

private static class DoubleListNode<E> {
    private E myData;
    private DoubleListNode<E> myNext;
    private DoubleListNode<E> myPrev;

    public DoubleListNode() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }
    
    public DoubleListNode(DoubleListNode<E> prev, E data,
            DoubleListNode<E> next) {
        myData = data;
        myNext = next;
        myPrev = prev;
    }
}

public void addLast(E data) {
    DoubleListNode<E> newNode = new DoubleListNode<E>(tail.myPrev, data, tail);
    if(size == 0) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        tail.myNext = newNode;
        newNode.myPrev = tail;
    }
    tail = newNode;
    size++;
}

public void displayList() {
    if (head == null) {
        
    }
    DoubleListNode<E> temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.print(temp.myData + " --> ");
        temp = temp.myNext;
    }
    System.out.println("Null");
}

public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Box<Integer> dl = new Box<Integer>();
    dl.addLast(5);
    dl.addLast(10);
    dl.displayList();
}
```

When I try to print the linked list the program is continuously running, but nothing is getting printed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint to see when the program gets stuck. (in `displayList` or in `addLast`) :) [edit: after reading the code it can't be stuck in addLast, but in general try to understand where the problem happens]

Comment: Are you familiar with a thing called “debugger”? Also, the oldest debugging technique, printing to stdout, still works.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code. It endlessly prints

> 5 --> 10 --> 5 --> 10 --> 5 --> 10 --> ...

It looks like you need to replace this line

```
DoubleListNode<E> newNode = new DoubleListNode<E>(tail.myPrev, data, tail);
```

with

```
DoubleListNode<E> newNode = new DoubleListNode<E>(tail, data, null);
```

In other words, when you add a new element you do not properly link it with the tail element.